# Cannot clean string from unwanted characters using Python beautifulsoup

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

When I run the following

```
prices = [price.text.strip() for price in soup.select('.special-price')]
prices = prices.replace(u'\xa0', u' ')
print(prices)
```

I get 'list' object has no attribute 'replace'

Where should I put the replace? is there any method to clear it with one step?

Thank you

Comment: Because **'list' object has no attribute 'replace'**

Comment: @Dirty Obviously yes but.. where and how?

Comment: Tried `prices = [price.replace(u'\xa0', u' ') for price in prices]`?

Comment: `data = prices[i].replace(u'\xa0', u' ')` ?

Comment: @idlehands local variable 'prices' referenced before assignment

Comment: Then just do it from the get go: `prices = [price.text.strip().replace(u'\xa0', u' ') for price in soup.select('.special-price')]`.  Though I'm unsure why you get that error.

Comment: is there any let's say priority of what someone should run first? first text then strip then replace all the time?

Comment: All the `.text` and `.strip` and `.replace` method will execute in each iteration.  The priority is as it is written - first `.text`, then `.strip`, then `.replace`.

Comment: @idlehands Its working thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because `'list' object has no attribute 'replace'`. That's why.

You're trying to change prices individually. String has `replace` method but a list has not.

You should add replace to your list comprehension.

```
prices = [price.text.strip().replace(u'\xa0', u' ') for price in soup.select('.special-price')]
print(prices)
```

Answer (score 1):

Since We do not have access to your sample data, this should do:

You need to put `replace()` on a `str` not a `list`, Like:

```
prices = ['1','1','2','3','4','5','1','1','1']
print([x.replace('1', '9') for x in prices])
```

**OUTPUT**:

```
['9', '9', '2', '3', '4', '5', '9', '9', '9']
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes because you created a list with list comprehension

You need to convert list to string by `prices=''.join(prices)` assuming the prices is list of string if not parse it to string. Prices will be a string then. Now you can call replace on it.